# Deriving equations for Back propagation of Gradient Penalty

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent, backpropagation, generative-adversarial-network

The forward pass looks like this:

Step 1.
Generate a mix batch of images:

```
X' = ε * real_image + ( 1 - ε) * generated_image
```

Step 2:
Pass X' through the discriminator network ( a FFN network) & calculate the loss.

Step 3:
Calculate gradients w.r.t to parameters of the discriminator network ( I can use the library functions for this)

Step 4: Calculate gradients w.r.t to `X'` & `ε`

This is what I've been unable to figure out. Given the gradients w.r.t to the parameters of the discriminator FFN, how do I compute gradients w.r.t `X'` & `ε`?

Pytorch makes it really easy since it has autograd. Equivalent pytorch code:

```
        epsilon_shape = [real_data.shape[0]] + [1]*(real_data.dim() - 1)
        epsilon = torch.rand(epsilon_shape)
        epsilon = epsilon.to(fake_data.device, fake_data.dtype)
        real_data = real_data.to(fake_data.dtype)
        x_hat = epsilon * real_data + (1-epsilon) * fake_data.detach()
        x_hat.requires_grad = True
        logits = self.discriminator(x_hat, condition, landmarks)
        logits = logits.sum()
        grad = torch.autograd.grad(
            outputs=logits,
            inputs=x_hat,
            grad_outputs=torch.ones(logits.shape).to(fake_data.dtype).to(fake_data.device),
            create_graph=True
        )[0]
```